# How to add custom properties/tags to an existing commit in JaVers?

Tags: javers

We currently use javers for tracking the history of several entities (Study, Survey, Data Set, Instrument). All these objects belong to the entity Project. Once a project is released - by saving it with a versionNumber property - I would like to tag the latest commit of the other entities with this versionNumber for instance by adding a custom commit property. This would be similar to git tagging.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there currently is a Javers API method to support this.

The only way I can think of doing what you need, is to get all available GlobalIDs and update the database directly with a script, setting the desired commit properties.

The DB schemas are not very complex so it's probably not very hard.

You would need to add each commit property in `jv_commit_property` and then modify each commit with the desired property.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to avoid this solution. However I will give it a try if no one comes up with a better answer.

Comment: Acapulco is right, JaVers Commits and Snapshots are immutable by design, although you can do SQL inserts on your own.